# Seeing duplicate requests handled with Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, unicorn

Recently I upgraded our EC2 instances to c3.large in order to boost more unicorn workers to handle increased traffic to our site. (6xworkers per machine - 2 ec2 instances).

When I did this, I started seeing duplicate records being created! It looks like somehow, that maybe 2 unicorn workers are attempting to process the same request?

In my nginx logs I see ONE [POST] request to a particular rails controller - yet two records are being created in the database. Obviously I'm hitting some kind of race condition issue - but have no idea how to debug this. It doesn't happen all the time, but when it does it's frustrating as well. I also noticed that the two database records are within 5 seconds of each other. (And yes I disable the button when the user clicks the submit button).

Unicorn 4.8.2
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.14

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not fix your problem, upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0.  There are some blog mentioning that is a good idea to upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 if you are using Unicorn.

For example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app

Specifically:

> If you are using Ruby 1.9, you should seriously consider
>   switching to Ruby 2.0. To understand why, we need to understand a
>   little bit about forking.

**Forking and Copy-on-Write (CoW)**

> When a child process is forked, it is
>   the exact same copy as the parent process. However, the actual
>   physical memory copied need not be made. Since they are exact copies,
>   both child and parent processes can share the same physical memory.
>   Only when a write is made-- then we copy the child process into
>   physical memory.

**So how does this relate to Ruby 1.9/2.0 and Unicorn?**

> Recall the Unicorn uses forking. In theory, the operating system would
>   be able to take advantage of CoW. Unfortunately, Ruby 1.9 does not
>   make this possible. More accurately, the garbage collection
>   implementation of Ruby 1.9 does not make this possible. An extremely
>   simplified version is this — when the garbage collector of Ruby 1.9
>   kicks in, a write would have been made, thus rendering CoW useless.
>
> Without going into too much detail, it suffices to say that the
>   garbage collector of Ruby 2.0 fixes this, and we can now exploit CoW.